# Cursor.Position resets automatically?

Tags: c#, position, cursor, point

**I have a simple method :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 200);
}
```

The cursor changes to the point (200,200) but as soon as the mouse is moved the cursor returns back to the original point (where the button is).

**I will note that I run this on 2 different computers, on one of them it is working fine, on the other the above problem occurs.**

Any suggestions ?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I would expect the cursor to change to the designated position and move from there...

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to a feature called Snap To and can be enabled or disabled from the control panel.

[image]

It makes that the mouse moves to a focussed button.

On other option you might try is to set the focus to a different control:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I have a pictureBox1 on my form that I could set the focus to
        this.pictureBox1.Focus();

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);
    }
```

Comment: How is the form started? Is it a dialog? This is a winforms app right? On which OS does it work and on which it doesn't? Did you try with an other control that can get the input focus (textbox for example instead of my picturebox). Which language settings are being used on each OS? is that a RTL language? Are there any other relevant plugins/mouse drivers/virusscanners installed? If you add all that info to your question (use the edit link) I'll have another look.

Comment: I am using a VM, there it dose not work, on my main OS it works fine. both are windows 7. I think a found what causes the problem, on the VM the mouse installed - shows there are 2 mouses! when i try disabling each , I found one controls the movement, and the other the clicks...and yes, the VM OS is LTR and the main is RTL.